# How can i combine two xpath so that i can click on edit icon based on the text displayed

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

In a grid, I want to click on edit icon but based on the text present in next column I want to click on edit icon.

For this I want to combine two xpath.

I have tried with this xpath

```
/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/following-sibling:://td[contains(text(),'m/s macro power contactors')]
```

Below is my HTML Code

```
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">…</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">…</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">…</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">…</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <a style="color:red;" title="Clike here to Edit"href="javascript:EditClick(3779)" class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130 green">…</a>
    </td>
    <td>m/s macro power contactors</td>
    <td>LC0063</td>
    <td>Local</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" class="even">…</tr>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">…</tr>
```

There is a edit icon for each of the row and i can click easily on edit icon without difficulty

What I am expecting is based on this "m/s macro power contactors" I want to click on edit icon against this.

Comment: Can you expand the `<a>` tag please? There seems to be some more child elements.

Comment: <a style="color:red;" title="Clike here to Edit" href="javascript:EditClick(3779)" class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130 green">    ::before    </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with the text and work your way up the html tree

```
//td[.='m/s macro power contactors']/preceding-sibling::td/a
```